# Given points $x,y$, and tangent vectors $v,w$, is there a diffeomorphism $x\mapsto y$ and $v\mapsto w$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, and you're given two points $x,y$, and associated tangent vectors $v$ and $w$. I'm curious, does there exist a diffeomorphism $F$ such that $F(x)=y$ and $dF_x(v)=w$?

I was playing around in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried the translation map $F(z)=z-x+y$, so $F(x)=y$. I let $\gamma:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be the curve defined by $\gamma(t)=x+tv$, but it turned out that
$$
dF_x(v)=dF_x(\gamma'(0))=(F\circ\gamma)'(0)=v
$$

Is it possible to make this work, hopefully for an arbitrary smooth manifold $M$? I don't mind assuming $M$ is connected, if that turns out to be a necessary hypothesis.

Comment: First move $x$ to $y$.  Then twist and stretch a little ball around $y$ (keeping the point $y$ fixed during the process) to move the tangent vector to where you want it.  Note that the twisting and stretching are confined to a little neighborhood of $y$, so you can use local coordinates and work in Euclidean space for that part of the construction.

Comment: The construction of Andreas Blass works. As you say, the connectedness is crucial. If a manifold consists of two components that are not diffeomorphic, and choosing x,y in those different components, than this is not possible of course.